# Creating of HDF5 file of SPSS file for and by Python

Tags: python, hdf5, spss

What is the easiest way to create a HDF5-file of an SPSS-file by Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already stumbled upon it, check out [h5py](http://code.google.com/p/h5py/). Iterating over SPSS's data with SPSS's addon python module, and placing the data in an h5py object should be all you need to do.

Comment: What is the easiest way to iterate through this SPSS file without having the SPSS-software itself ?

Comment: I haven't found any python packages that can parse an SPSS `.sav` file without SPSS itself, but I have noticed a [few](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577811-python-reader-writer-for-spss-sav-files-linux-mac-/) code snippets that might be robust enough for your needs. Beyond this, you might have better luck with reading the SPSS file with [R](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/read.spss.html) and then dumping out a CSV or some other easy-to-parse format. R uses [PSPP](http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/)'s SPSS reader, which (I expect) is more mature.

Comment: I have the same *.sav dataset in a *.sas7bdat format of SAS, is that easier to work with through Python you think ?

Comment: Every SPSS reader/importer I've run across seems to target the `.sav` format, so I'm guessing that's your better bet. R also has a specialized `sas7bdat` [reader](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sas7bdat/index.html) as well, but if you have the same content in both formats, the `.sav` file seems better supported.

Answer (score 0):

The Python code at this link
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577811-python-reader-writer-for-spss-sav-files-linux-mac-/
reads and write sav files.  It uses the free i/o modules produced by IBM SPSS.